# Grouped json conversion

Tags: r, json, dplyr, purrr

I want to do a groupwise conversion to JSON, with the grouping variable in the first column of the resulting tibble. The code below works as expected, but it is ugly - especially the need for the final `pivot_longer`. I tried with `map_dfr` and `map_dfc` but could not get it right.

Any more elegant solution?

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  purrr::map_df(~jsonlite::toJSON(.x)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(everything())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   name  value
#>   <chr> <json>
#> 1 4     [{"mpg":22.8,"cyl":4,"disp":108,"hp":93,"drat":3.85,"wt":2.32,"qsec":18~
#> 2 6     [{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3.9,"wt":2.62,"qsec":16.4~
#> 3 8     [{"mpg":18.7,"cyl":8,"disp":360,"hp":175,"drat":3.15,"wt":3.44,"qsec":1~
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use use `map_df()` on the split data like so:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  map_df(~ list(value = jsonlite::toJSON(.x)), .id = "cyl")

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  cyl   value                                                                                                                                         
  <chr> <vct:::__>                                                                                                                                    
1 4     [{"mpg":22.8,"cyl":4,"disp":108,"hp":93,"drat":3.85,"wt":2.32,"qsec":18.61,"vs":1,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":1,"_row":"Datsun 710"},{"mpg":24.4,"~
2 6     [{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3.9,"wt":2.62,"qsec":16.46,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"_row":"Mazda RX4"},{"mpg":21,"cyl":~
3 8     [{"mpg":18.7,"cyl":8,"disp":360,"hp":175,"drat":3.15,"wt":3.44,"qsec":17.02,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":2,"_row":"Hornet Sportabout"},{"mpg~
```

Or using `summarise()` on the grouped data (thanks Ronak for suggesting `cur_data()`):

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(value = jsonlite::toJSON(cur_data()))
```

Comment: I had failed using `.data`, but was not aware of `cur_data`. Thanks to @Ronak Shah too, even if I did see him mentioning `cur_data` - I assume "personal communication"

Answer (score 2):

You can `nest` the dataframe and use `rowwise` to convert data into json.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  tidyr::nest(value = -cyl) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(value = jsonlite::toJSON(value))

#    cyl value                                                                     
#  <dbl> <json>                                                                    
#1     6 [{"mpg":21,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3.9,"wt":2.62,"qsec":16.46,"vs":0,"…
#2     4 [{"mpg":22.8,"disp":108,"hp":93,"drat":3.85,"wt":2.32,"qsec":18.61,"vs":1…
#3     8 [{"mpg":18.7,"disp":360,"hp":175,"drat":3.15,"wt":3.44,"qsec":17.02,"vs":…
```